# If I run the azure WebJob each one hour, I am getting 30 minute late notification in India standard time zone

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I am running my azure webjob each one hour in UTc time zone. Due to that in Indian standard Time zone I'm getting notification after 30 minute.

Ex : If except notification for 6 PM then I am Getting 6:30 PM , Same Like 7 PM Means 7:30 PM.

I Know the problem with time difference between UTC AND IST time zone. Because, It is difference (05:30 hour) the problem with 30 minute.

Ex : if webjob run at 12:00 pm then this time in india/IST(5:30 pm) and next webjob will run at 01:00 pm then this time in india/IST(6:30 pm) in this time I'm getting notification but I need exact 6 PM.

Can you please suggest how to fix the solution?

And can we run azure webjob IST time zone?

I checked we can run azure webjob on IST time zone might be but it's not support for LINUX.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the CRON expression to `0 30 * * * *` to run it at the 30-minute mark to offset for the time difference.

This would run it at 12:30, 1:30, 2:30, etc. instead.